# Difference between Launch Screen and Launch Image

Tags: ios, xcode, image, screen, launch

What exactly is the difference between Launch Screen and Launch Image? I know what an Launch Screen is. When starting an app you see the Launch Screen while the app is loading. When app is loaded Launch Screen disappears, right? But, what is an Launch Image?

Comment: The same thing, but older.

Comment: For iOS 7 an earlier?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Launch Image**:

A default image to be shown while your app loads. Many people use this as a splash screen for branding. You can still use these except you need to cut one per screen size/orientation.

**Launch Screen: new in iOS 8**

A default screen shown while the app loads. Your launch screen storyboard file is rendered into an image and shown the same way as your "launch image". This means you can create a single resource storyboard file that will adapt to many screen sizes, rather than having to cut an image per screen size, and not need to worry about naming conventions.